# Does innerHTML Work Across Different Lines?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use innerHTML to create a drop list from the user's input, but it doesn't work. The code below outputs an empty drop list. The problem seems to be splitting up the `<select>` and `<option>` writes on separate lines. If I put the `<select>` and `</select>` inside the for loop, it works, but it creates a separate drop list for every item. Any ideas?

```
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "<select>";
for (ddNum=0; ddNum <= ddWanted; ddNum++)
{
var ddIDvar = document.getElementById('inputID' + ddNum);
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "<option>" + ddIDvar.value + "</option>";
}
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "</select><br />";
```

Answer (score 3):

The browser may be mungeing the HTML you're adding in, trying to make it "proper" by adding closing tags. Instead of repeatedly appending incomplete tag setes to the .innerHTML and forcing a potentially expensive reflow/redraw, build your select as a string, then append it to .innerHTML once it's done:

```
var sel = '<select>';
for (ddNum ...) {
   sel += '<option>....</option>';
}
sel += '</select>';
.... .innerHTML += sel;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't set `innerHTML` to half of an HTML tag.
If you try, the browser will fix it for you, which isn't what you want.

You need to assemble a complete string of HTML, then set `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to trigger a reflow every time you change the value of innerHTML, which is not good for performance.  Instead, build the string of HTML up ahead of time and write innerHTML once:

```
var s = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML + "<select>";
for (ddNum=0; ddNum <= ddWanted; ddNum++)
{
    var ddIDvar = document.getElementById('inputID' + ddNum);
    s += "<option>" + ddIDvar.value + "</option>";
}
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = s + "</select><br />";
```